# Elevation to power function using class templates

Tags: c++, c++11, template

I attached below a small working example of a function that is able to perform `x^y`. As it is possible to see the base (x) takes `double` and the power takes an `int`. As last the `main` loop will also round up or down the result accordingly.

Not always I have these type of formats, and I could have base as `int` and power as `double` or base as `long int` and power as additional type. How can I improve this function to make it more general with different type format using template `template <class identifier>` or/and `template <typename identifier>`?

```
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Power {
public:
    double raiseToPower(double x, int power)
    {
        double result;
        int i;
        result = 1.0;
        for(i = 1; i <=power; i++){
            result = result*x;
        }
        return result;
    }

    double floor0(double num)
      {
        if( (num + 0.5) >= (int(num) + 1) )
        return int(num)+1;
        else
        return int(num);
    }
};


int main()
{
    double x;
    int i;
    Power example;
    std::cout<<"please enter the number"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>x;
    std::cout<<"please enter the integer power that you want this number raised to"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>i;
    std::cout<<"rise to power "<<i<<" is equal to "<<example.raiseToPower(x,i)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"the result rounded is "<< example.floor0(example.raiseToPower(x,i))<<std::endl;
}
```

Thank for any insight and point to the right direction.

Comment: Is something wrong with [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) though?

Comment: @Juho, thank for reading my question, there is nothing wrong with `std::pow` but I would like to have another way of expressing this type of function or future functions

Comment: The logic you have for raiseToPower currently will only work for positive integer exponents.  So before you can meaningfully support other types as exponents, you need to expand that.

Comment: @Errorsatz, thanks for your comment and for reading the question, how could I modify the function and make it better then?

Comment: Are you from Java? Your functions make more sense being free functions in C++.

Comment: @L.F., thank for your comment and for reading the question. No I am from C++ I was wondering how to make that function better using template function for my future reference

Comment: For fractional exponents, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606734/calculate-fractional-exponent-in-for-loop-without-power-function might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Headers and namespaces

Don't `using namespace`, especially a big and growing namespace like `std` that's not designed for it.

There's no need to include `<cmath>`.  On the other hand, there is a clear need for `<iostream>`, which has been omitted.

## Structure

There's no need for the `Power` class; it maintains no state.  The functions should simply be free functions, perhaps in a namespace.

## Consider full range of types

`raiseToPower()` only works with non-negative exponents; it should either accept an unsigned type or be modified to work correctly with negative inputs.  Perhaps like this:

```
    if (power < 0) {
        return raiseToPower(1/x, -power);
    }
```

## Improve the algorithm

For large `power`, the loop is executed many times.  We can use *binary exponentation* to reduce that to `log₂ power` iterations of the loop.

## Avoid over-complication

`floor0()` doesn't need that `if`/`else`; simply add 0.5 *before* truncating:

```
constexpr double floor0(double num)
{
    return int(num + 0.5);
}
```

It might be better to use `long` or `long long` there; in any case, you'll still suffer bugs when the value is too big for the integer type.  `std::floor()` doesn't have that problem.

## Validate inputs

If I enter a non-number, I don't get a clear error message.  Instead, the program uses uninitialised values, which is Undefined Behaviour.  Don't do that; instead check that `std::cin` is still good before using `x` or `i`.

## Avoid `std::endl` unless you need output flushing

None of the uses of `std::endl` here are necessary, and we can use `\n` instead.  (Remember that using `std::cin` flushes the output streams, and returning from `main()` also flushes outputs).

---

## Modified code

```
double raiseToPower(double x, int power)
{
    if (power < 0) {
        return raiseToPower(1/x, -power);
    }

    double result = 1.0;
    double m = x;

    for (;  power;  power /= 2) {
        if (power % 2) {
            result *= m;
        }
        m *= m;
    }
    return result;
}

constexpr double floor0(double num)
{
    return int(num + 0.5);
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double x;
    int i;
    std::cout << "Please enter the number\n";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Please enter the integer power that "
                 "you want this number raised to\n";
    std::cin >> i;
    if (!std::cin) {
        std::cerr << "Input format error\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto const result = raiseToPower(x,i);
    std::cout << x << " raised to power " << i << " is equal to "
              << result << '\n';
    std::cout << "The result rounded is "
              << floor0(result) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the very detailed and comprehensive explanation on how to improve the code! Exactly what I was looking for! :)